# pry 上で Bigdecimalの表示を読みやすくする

Tags: ruby, pry

`float`だと小数点以下の数字を扱う時にずれるので`BigDecimal`をよく使うんですが、`pry`上で値を確認したい時に

```
"0.003".to_d
=> #<BigDecimal:7fbba791fba8,'0.3E-2',9(18)>
```

のようにひと目でわかりにくいので、いつも`to_f`をつけて値の確認をしています。

毎回そのように打つのは非効率的なので`pry`上でBigdecimal`を使ったら`0.003[BigDecimal]`のように表示をわかりやすくするプラグインや設定はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AwesomePrintというgemを常に有効化すると良いかもしれません。
僕のpryだとこんなふうに実行されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

まず AwesomePrintをインストールします。

```
$ gem install awesome_print
```

次に `~/.pryrc` を編集します。

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.pry!
```

これでpryを起動すれば自動的にAwesomePrintが有効化されます。

ちなみに僕はrbenv-default-gemsを使って、Rubyインストール時にpryやAwesomePrintも自動的にインストールされるようにしています。

```
$ cat ~/.rbenv/default-gems 
bundler 
pry 
pry-byebug 
awesome_print 
powder
```

参考：[rubygems - rbenvでrubyをインストールした時に、指定したgemを自動的に入れてくれるようにする - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mapyo/items/edcc7664d40391e800db)